# Forms in PHP: Use predefined values ​if users do not fill out forms

Tags: php, forms

I'm making a form using PHP and HTML. I want the form to use a predetermined value if the user does not fill out the form.

**Default value:**

- Name: Jhon
- Email: @example.com
- Message: Without message

**This is the PHP code that I use to process data:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    if(trim($_POST['contactName']) === '') {
        $nameError = 'Please enter your name.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $name = trim($_POST['contactName']);
    }

    if(trim($_POST['email']) === '')  {
        $emailError = 'Please enter your email address.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i", trim($_POST['email']))) {
        $emailError = 'You entered an invalid email address.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    }

    if(trim($_POST['comments']) === '') {
        $commentError = 'Please enter a message.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
            $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['comments']));
        } else {
            $comments = trim($_POST['comments']);
        }
    }

    if(!isset($hasError)) {
        $emailTo = get_option('tz_email');
        if (!isset($emailTo) || ($emailTo == '') ){
            $emailTo = get_option('admin_email');
        }
        $subject = '[PHP Snippets] From '.$name;
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments: $comments";
        $headers = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

        wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
        $emailSent = true;
    }

}
```

**And here is the HTML I used:**

```
<?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { ?>
                            <div class="thanks">
                                <p>Thanks, your email was sent successfully.</p>
                            </div>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                            <?php if(isset($hasError) || isset($captchaError)) { ?>
                                <p class="error">Sorry, an error occured.<p>
                            <?php } ?>

                        <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
                            <ul class="contactform">
                            <li>
                                <label for="contactName">Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="contactName" id="contactName" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['contactName'])) echo $_POST['contactName'];?>" class="required requiredField" />
                                <?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
                                    <span class="error"><?=$nameError;?></span>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email']))  echo $_POST['email'];?>" class="required requiredField email" />
                                <?php if($emailError != '') { ?>
                                    <span class="error"><?=$emailError;?></span>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </li>

                            <li><label for="commentsText">Message:</label>
                                <textarea name="comments" id="commentsText" rows="20" cols="30" class="required requiredField"><?php if(isset($_POST['comments'])) { if(function_exists('stripslashes')) { echo stripslashes($_POST['comments']); } else { echo $_POST['comments']; } } ?></textarea>
                                <?php if($commentError != '') { ?>
                                    <span class="error"><?=$commentError;?></span>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <input type="submit">Send email</input>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
                    </form>
                <?php } ?>
```

**How do I make the values sent use the default values if the user does not fill out the form?**

Answer (score 1):

use  **?:** ( Ternary Operator)

```
$email = $_POST['email'] ?: 'default Email';
```

The above is identical to this if/else statement

```
if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = 'default Email';
} else {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}
```

use this logic for those element you want to set a default value.

Comment: Can you enter this code into my PHP code? I want to see it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `??` operator:

```
$email = $_POST['email'] ?? 'defaultemail@example.com';
```

It's the equivalent to doing a `empty()` and assigning the default value if it is empty:

```
$email = NULL;
if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
} else {
    $email = 'defaultemail@example.com';
}
```

Comment: Can you enter this code into my PHP code? I want to see it clearly.